# Let $\alpha_n := \inf_{x\in K_n} \varphi (x)$. Prove that $(\alpha_n)$ is convergent and identify its limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to solve below exercise, i.e.,

> Let $H$ be a non-empty set. Let $(K_n)$ be an increasing sequence of subsets of $H$. Let $\varphi:H \to \mathbb R$ be bounded from below. Let $\alpha_n := \inf_{x\in K_n} \varphi (x)$. Prove that $(\alpha_n)$ is convergent and identify its limit.

Could you have a check on my attempt?

---

Let $\beta := \inf_{x\in H} \varphi (x)$. Then $\beta > -\infty$ because $\varphi$ is bounded from below. Because $K_n \subset K_{n+1}$, we get $\alpha_n \ge \alpha_{n+1} \ge \beta$. Then $(\alpha_n)$ is convergent. Let $\alpha := \lim_n \alpha_n$. Let $K := \bigcup_n K_n$ and $\alpha' := \inf_{x\in K} \varphi (x)$. Then $\alpha \ge \alpha'$. We will prove that $\alpha \le \alpha'$. There is a sequence $(x_n) \subset K$ such that $\varphi(x_n) \downarrow \alpha'$. For each $n$, there is $\lambda(n) \in \mathbb N$ such that $x_n \in K_{\lambda (n)}$. This implies $\varphi (x_n) \ge \alpha_{\lambda(n)} \ge \alpha$. Then $\lim_n \varphi (\alpha_n) \ge \alpha$. This completes the proof.

Comment: The proof is fine and $\alpha=\inf \bigcup \varphi(K_n.)$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thank you so much for your verification!